# Reproject image collection according to the projection of another image collection

Tags: coordinate-system, google-earth-engine, sentinel-2, sentinel-1

I have two image colelctions. one of sentinel 1 and one of sentinel 2.
I want to reproject the sentinel 1 so its' projection and cell size would be like the sentunel 2 images.
It worked for me when I did it without function on only one image, but now when I have ttried to create a function for this, when I check the results I see that the pixels of the two polygons do not sit on top of each other, e.g seems like the reprojection didn't work.

This is my function:

```
////Fix reproject SAR 1////

var SARresample=Clipped_Speckles.map(function(im){
  var sar1Projection =  im.projection();
  var NDVIProjection =  ee.Image(listOfImages.get(listOfNumbers[0])).projection();
  var SARreproject=im.reduceResolution({reducer: ee.Reducer.mean()}).reproject({crs: NDVIProjection});

   return im;
});
```

after the function. I have tried to display two images in order to see the pixels but it seems like the function didn't function:

```
//Visualize the resample vs NDVI 

var listOfIResamples =(SARresample.toList(SARresample.size()));

var NumberOfImagesSAR=[0];

var ResampledIM= ee.Image(listOfIResamples.get(NumberOfImagesSAR[0]));

Map.addLayer(ResampledIM,{bands: 'VH_Filtered',min: -30, max: 1},'SAR');


//visualize NDVI

var listOfImagesNDVI =(filterNDVI.toList(filterNDVI.size()));

var NumberOfImagesNDVI=[0,1,2];

var ndviIM= ee.Image(listOfImagesNDVI.get(NumberOfImagesNDVI[1]));

Map.addLayer(ndviIM, NDVIcolor,'NDVI');
```

Here you can see the full code:

https://code.earthengine.google.com/0b322b779162bc1eb18a6143867d1a99

*I have changed the speckle filter size to 2 for it to be easier to see the pixels.

*the polygon is in north of Thailand , cannot share it but any random polygon in that area will work.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `projection()` on an `ee.Image` object returns an `ee.Projection` object. In your function you are providing the projection object to the `crs` parameter of the `reproject()` image method. Use `.crs()` on the projection object to retrieve its CRS:

```js
.reproject({crs: NDVIProjection.crs()});
```

I would also probably define the `scale` parameter as well:

```js
NDVIProjection.nominalScale()
```

Note, however, that using `reproject()` is not good practice. If you want data to be in the same projection, all region reducing and export functions allow you to specify it - which is where you should be doing it, instead of with `reproject()`.

Please see [Reprojecting](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/projections#reprojecting) and the "Caution" section of [Object-based methods](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/image_objects) for more information.